# Pythom:Compare 2 columns and write data to excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, dataframe

1. I need to compare two columns together: "EMAIL" and "LOCATION".
2. I'm using Email because it's more accurate than name for this issue.
3. My objective is to find total number of locations each person worked
   at, sum up the total of locations to select which sheet the data
   will been written to and copy the original data over to the new
   sheet(tab).
4. I need the original data copied over with all the duplicate
   locations, which is where this problem stumps me.

[Full Excel Sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iAiQaM8pH0T8L62eo8YgyOg4FDAx22mY/view?usp=sharing)

Had to use images because it flagged post as spam

The Excel sheet (SAMPLE) I'm reading in as a data frame: 
    [Excel Sample Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8t8N.jpg)

Example:

> TOMAPPLES@EXAMPLE.COM worked at WENDYS,FRANKS HUT, and WALMART -  That
>   sums up to 3 different locations, which I would add to a new sheet
>   called *SHEET: 3 Different Locations*
>
> SJONES22@GMAIL.COM worked at LONDONS TENT and YOUTUBE - That's 2 different locations, which I would add to a new sheet called *SHEET:
>   2 Different Locations*
>
> MONTYJ@EXAMPLE.COM worked only at WALMART - This user would be added
>   to *SHEET: 1 Location*

Outcome:

- data copied to new sheets

#### Sheet 2

[Sheet 2: different locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3rZv.jpg)

#### Sheet 3

[Sheet 3: different locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk10M.jpg)

#### Sheet 4

[Sheet 4: different locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66w9B.jpg)

Thanks for taking your time looking at my problem =)

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Hi Check below lines if work for you..

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')

df1 = df.groupby(['Name','Location','Job']).count().reset_index()

# this is long line
df2 = df.groupby(['Name','Location','Job','Email']).agg({'Location':'count','Email':'count'}).rename(columns={'Location':'Location Count','Email':'Email Count'}).reset_index()

print(df1)
print('\n\n')
print(df2)
```

[image]

below is the output change columns to check more variations

df1

```
        Name Location      Job  Email
0          Monty  Jakarta  Manager      1
1          Monty   Mumbai  Manager      1
2  Sahara Jonesh    Paris     Cook      2
3        Tom App  Jakarta    Buser      1
4        Tom App    Paris    Buser      2
```

df2 all columns

```
            Name Location  ... Location Count Email Count
0          Monty  Jakarta  ...              1           1
1          Monty   Mumbai  ...              1           1
2  Sahara Jonesh    Paris  ...              2           2
3        Tom App  Jakarta  ...              1           1
4        Tom App    Paris  ...              2           2
```

Comment: Hey Kumar! Thanks for the response, this is great! One thing though, in my question the User had different Jobs and Locations. The output you have would be perfect if other jobs/locations can be added to this.

EX:
Tom App, also worked at Iceland. -- The location would be 2 even though "London" was mentioned twice.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Koal , few change is done let me know if you need count and values both